# Building geth from the bsc project fails with "checksum mismatch"

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc

I have cloned the `bsc` project from [binance-chain on github](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc) and building from the `master` branch fails to with the following message:

```
make geth
```

Output:

```
env GO111MODULE=on go run build/ci.go install ./cmd/geth
>>> /usr/lib/go-1.14/bin/go install -ldflags -X main.gitCommit=46d185b4cfed54436f526b24c47b15ed58a5e1bb -X main.gitDate=20210403 -v ./cmd/geth
go: downloading github.com/btcsuite/btcd v0.20.0-beta
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20190819201941-24fa4b261c55
verifying github.com/btcsuite/btcd@v0.20.0-beta: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:DnZGUjFbRkpytojHWwy6nfUSA7vFrzWXDLpFNzt74ZA=
    go.sum:     h1:PamBMopnHxO2nEIsU89ibVVnqnXR2yFTgGNc+PdG68o=
```

Is this a bug, or might I have some misconfiguration locally?

Here are the `go` and `gcc` versions I am using:

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, source https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16613#issuecomment-407054242

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`